# Mongoose custom error message when data type fails

Tags: express, mongoose

I have `phone` field in my mongodb schema with type is `Number`

```
phone:{
       type:Number,
       required:[true,"Phone Number required"]
   }
```

If the phone number contains a character other than number it will throw a default error message

```
Cast to Array failed for value \"887878jjk\" at path \"phone\
```

But i want to customize this error message like "Allow only numbers" One solution i found from mogoose doc is write a custom validator for this

```
validate: {
          validator: function(v) {
            return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
          },
          message: '{VALUE} is not a valid phone number!'
        },
```

But is there any other solution to without using a custom validator??

Comment: No. That's the only way. Short of writing a plugin of course. But if you don't want to write a custom validator then since that would be more work, I guess it's not an option. Simple things just do what they do. Extensible things are more complex so they can be, ...umm etxensible!

Comment: The point is `Number` type is already validate the field then again writing a custom validator(Remember:Its only for  an error message)  seems breaking DRY rules somewhere else

Comment: Yeah but what you want is a "custom" response. Get it? You get a simple string with a simple validator. No templates or built in standard variables. If you want something better, then write it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this on your model schema:

```
phone: {
type: String,
validate: {
  validator: function(v) {
    return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
  },
  message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
},
required:[true,"Phone Number required"]
```

Hope it helps.